# Number of ways people $3$ men and $7$ women can fit in three cars given the stated restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

3 men, 7 women and a married couple travel together with three cars. Each car can only fit four people. Given that all of them can drive cars, find the number of ways they can get in the car such that:

(i) everyone in each car must be same gender,

(ii) a married couple must sit together in a car

Comment: Can you share your workings? :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please, try to solve the problem yourself first and tell us where you are stuck. We are here to help, but not to solve your homework instead of you :-)

Comment: The two rules appear to be in conflict unless we are to assume a same gender marriage, in which case we need to know which gender.

Comment: Should (i) be every unmarried person in a car must be the same gender?

Comment: Are the cars identical ? Or is having four people in car A a different arrangement from having the same four people in car B ?

Comment: It's hard to imagine any reasonable modification of the rules that makes this possible.  The unmarried women must be split between at least two cars, so the unmarried men must all be in one car which can not then take the married couple.  That then leaves $9$ people to divide between two cars, which can not be done.

Comment: @lulu I suspect the two conditions are meant to be separate questions.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Ah, at least that gives rise to some solutions.

Comment: @lulu Condition (i) cannot be met in the case of a same-gender marriage, though I agree that the problem statement ought to specify the genders of the couple. The problem statement also neglects to specify whether any of the other ten people is married to any of the others.

Comment: There's also the question of whether a person in the front seat and a person in the back seat of the same car are "sitting together."

Comment: I think the OP should clarify the question (or questions, as the case may be).

Comment: There are two separate questions, scenarios given here in (i) and (ii). This is how the question was given, I did no modification to the question. So I have no idea whether sitting together means different for sitting in the front and back seat. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

(i) group of men already decided , left 8 women need to be divided in 2 groups each of 4 which has $\frac{8!}{4!4!2!}$ ways =35.Now we are left with 3 groups which are to be arranged in 3 cars(assuming cars are different) hence multiply 70 by 3!=210

(ii) We will choose 2 people who sit with married couple, and then reapeat the whole process entirely as done is first case=210×45

Comment: Hello Aryan Bansai,Thank you very much for your response. Can you please elaborate a little bit on the part where you divide by 4!4!2!.? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: We select 4 people from 8 which is ${8  \choose  4}$.What we are looking for is groups what's wrong here is lets say we chose 1,2,3,4 or we chose 5,6,7,8 . Both choice give same groups ,so every case is counted 2 times. Now lets say you have to form 3 groups each of 2 from 6 people. That should be $ {6 \choose 2}.{4 \choose 2}.{2 \choose 2}$ = $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$. Now the wrong thing in our calculation is lets say you first chose 1,2 then 3,4 then 5,6 but 2,4 then 1,2 then 5,6 wields same groups .Notice every case will be repeated 3! times.So final answer is $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!3!}$

Comment: Now lets say it's say 2 groups of 4 and 3 from 7 people then number of cases simply is $\frac{7!}{4!3!}$ and no repetition seen here. Now say we have to form 4 groups of 3,3,2,2 from 10 people then simply it should $\frac{10!}{3!3!2!2!}$ but we will see repetition due to 3,3 and also due to 2,2 so we will have to divide the previous thing by 2! '2' times. So final answer is $\frac{10!}{2!2!3!3!2!2!}$. Now by using this we can solve the number of cases of so and so groups from this much peope. I am sorry if all this is not understandable.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this to me. This was very helpful. Thanks again.